# Error when trying to consume web services using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, web-services, jquery

I am new to jquery. I am trying to consume the web services of *http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?op=GetGeoIP* using the html and jquery. I have written the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <page language ="html" validateRequest="false">
   <html>
<head>
     <title>Hello There</title>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"> type="text/javascript" > </script>
</head>
<body>
      <div>
        IPAddress: <input type="text" name="id" id="theId"/>
        <br />
        <button id="getRemoteResponseBt">Get remote response</button>
      </div>
      <script>
        var url='http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?op=GetGeoIP';
        var dataMessage=
         '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> \
         <soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"     xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"> \
         <soap:Body> \
         <GetGeoIP xmlns="http://www.webservicex.net/"> \
         <IPAddress>+theId.val()+</IPAddress> \
         </GetGeoIP> \
         </soap:Body> \
         </soap:Envelope>';

$("#getRemoteResponseBt").click(function() {
   $.ajax({
     url: url,
     dataType: "xml",
     data: dataMessage,
     processData: false,
     contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\"",
     success: function(text) {
       var xml = $(text);
       var id = xml.find('IP').text();
       var name = xml.find('CountryName').text();
       var code = xml.find('CountryCode').text();
       alert("Result:" + id +name+code);
     },
     error:function (xhr) {
       alert(xhr.responseText+"Error");
     }
   });
 return false;
 });        
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I click on the Button, every time it give error. Can anybody please help in making the code work? For web service description check the link :http://www.webservicex.net/geoipservice.asmx?op=GetGeoIP

Comment: *What* error exactly?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply deceze . I am getting the error as 'undefined' in the alert. You can run this code in html file and check.

Comment: Is the success function called? Or the error function? What is the content of text? The content of `xml`? The content of `id`? `name`? `code`?

Answer (score 1):

That is attempting a cross domain post from your domain to *webservicex.net* which is prohibited by the browser's [same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) unless the receiving server implements CORS, which it does not.

The API is designed to be called from a server side script where same origin does not apply, so you will need to find an alternate service or create a proxy script on your domain.

Comment: [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/wE2vS/) is a fiddle I was doing to see the error. I let it here if one want to see the error in his browser's console